# How to replace matching with value from next column in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame:

```
structure(list(City = structure(c(4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Gold Cost", 
"Melbourne", "Other", "Sydney"), class = "factor"), Town = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("", "Brighton", "Hurstville", 
"Penhurst"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("City", "Town"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I want to replace all rows from column named City which contains value named Other and replace it with value from next column of same rows.

My output should look like this:

```
structure(list(City = structure(c(6L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("Brighton", 
"Gold Cost", "Hurstville", "Melbourne", "Penhurst", "Sydney"), class = "factor"), 
    Town = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
    "Brighton", "Hurstville", "Penhurst"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("City", 
"Town"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I haven't written any function before but I am guessing it should look like this:

```
for(data1 in 1:nrow(data1)) {
        if(data1$City[i] == 'Other') {
                data1$city[i] <- data1$Town[i]
        } else {
                break
        }
}
```

1. Where did I go wrong?
2. What should be the thinking process to solve problem like this in future?
3. How can I get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 errors and 2 inefficiencies.

**Error 1**:
You wrote `for(data1` instead of `for(i` .

**Error 2:** Your class is `factor` for `City` and you're trying to add new levels. Instead change it to `character` for this operation. Otherwise the new factor level is converted to `NA`. There are other ways of fixing this problem but they are less efficient; you can always change it back to factor afterwards.

**Inefficiency 1:**
You also don't need the `else` statement.

**Inefficiency 2:** You could've done this without a `for` loop (i.e. in a vectorized way).

```
data1 <- structure(list(City = structure(c(4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
.Label = c("Gold Cost", "Melbourne", "Other", "Sydney"), class = "factor"), 
                        Town = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L),
 .Label = c("", "Brighton", "Hurstville", "Penhurst"), class = "factor")), 
                   .Names = c("City", "Town"), class = "data.frame",
   row.names = c(NA, -6L))

desired_output <- structure(list(City = structure(c(6L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L),
 .Label = c("Brighton", "Gold Cost", "Hurstville", "Melbourne", "Penhurst", "Sydney"),
  class = "factor"), Town = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L), 
 .Label = c("", "Brighton", "Hurstville", "Penhurst"), class = "factor")), 
  .Names = c("City", "Town"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -6L))

data1$City <- as.character(data1$City)
data1$Town <- as.character(data1$Town)
for(i in 1:nrow(data1)){
  if(data1$City[i]=='Other'){
    data1$City[i]<- data1$Town[i]
  }
}

data1
```

> ```
>         City       Town
> 1     Sydney           
> 2  Melbourne           
> 3  Gold Cost           
> 4 Hurstville Hurstville
> 5   Penhurst   Penhurst
> 6   Brighton   Brighton
> ```

```
data1 == desired_output
```

> ```
>      City Town
> [1,] TRUE TRUE
> [2,] TRUE TRUE
> [3,] TRUE TRUE
> [4,] TRUE TRUE
> [5,] TRUE TRUE
> [6,] TRUE TRUE
> ```

Now for the vectorized solution. By avoiding using loops your code will run exponentially faster and you also have to type less code.

```
data1$City[data1$City == "Other"] <- data1$Town[data1$City == "Other"]
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you so much @Hack-R for helping out.